# Cannot read property 'emit' of null on Npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, request

Npm install is failing with this error `Cannot read property 'emit' of null` on executing `npm install` command

Here are the Dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
  "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "bootstrap-loader": "^1.0.10",
  "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "chai-enzyme": "^0.4.1",
  "classnames": "^2.2.3",
  "copyfiles": "^0.2.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
  "enzyme": "^2.2.0",
  "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
  "eslint": "^2.7.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.2.0",
  "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-control-statements": "^1.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
  "fetch-mock": "^4.3.0",
  "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
  "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
  "fs": "0.0.2",
  "glob": "^7.0.3",
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-cli": "^0.1.10",
  "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
  "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.0.1",
  "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
  "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.11",
  "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
  "immutable": "^3.7.6",
  "isparta-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "jsonpath-plus": "^0.15.0",
  "jsx-control-statements": "^3.1.0",
  "karma": "^0.13.22",
  "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
  "karma-jsdom-launcher": "^3.0.0",
  "karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-osx-reporter": "^0.2.1",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
  "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.1.1",
  "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
  "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
  "marked": "^0.3.5",
  "mocha": "^2.4.5",
  "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
  "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
  "open": "0.0.5",
  "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
  "pluralize": "^1.2.1",
  "pm2": "^3.5.1",
  "postcss": "^5.0.19",
  "postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.7",
  "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^0.14.8",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.8",
  "react-autosize-textarea": "^0.3.4",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.5",
  "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
  "react-datagrid": "^2.0.2",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
  "react-mixin": "^3.0.4",
  "react-overlays": "^0.6.1",
  "react-router": "^2.0.1",
  "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
  "react-tabs": "^0.5.3",
  "react-textarea-autosize": "^4.0.5",
  "redux-act": "^0.4.0",
  "redux-logger": "^2.6.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
  "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
  "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
  "sass-resources-loader": "^1.0.2",
  "sinon": "^2.0.0-pre",
  "skin-deep": "^0.16.0",
  "sorty": "^1.2.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
  "velocity-react": "^1.1.4",
  "webpack": "^1.12.14",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
  "webpack-sources": "^0.1.1",
  "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "async": "^1.5.2",
  "bluebird": "^3.5.4",
  "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
  "compression": "^1.6.2",
  "config": "^1.19.0",
  "connect": "^3.4.1",
  "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
  "connect-redis": "^3.0.2",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
  "core-js": "^2.2.1",
  "debug": "^2.2.0",
  "elasticsearch": "^11.0.1",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "express-session": "^1.13.0",
  "express-winston": "^1.4.1",
  "form-data": "^2.1.2",
  "jade": "^1.11.0",
  "lodash": "^4.6.1",
  "minimist": "^1.2.0",
  "moment": "^2.12.0",
  "newrelic": "^1.26.0",
  "node-cache": "4.1.1",
  "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
  "normalize.css": "^3.0.3",
  "numeral": "^1.5.3",
  "passport": "^0.4.1",
  "passport-azure-ad": "^3.0.0",
  "passport-saml": "^1.3.3",
  "react": "^0.14.8",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
  "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
  "redis": "^2.6.1",
  "redux": "^3.3.1",
  "request": "^2.69.0",
  "request-id": "^0.11.0",
  "winston": "^2.2.0",
  "winston-graylog2": "^0.5.0",
  "wkhtmltopdf": "^0.3.0"
}
}
```

In error logs it shows error at **TLSSocket.connectionErrorHandler**. Below provided are the detail Error logs

```
npm verb stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of null
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.connectionErrorHandler 

(C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v5.11.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:82:24)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.g (events.js:273:16)
npm verb stack     at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:7)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1265:8)
npm verb stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
npm verb stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Versions**

```
Node: v5.11.1
NPM: v3.8.6
```

Please help me to resolve this error. Spend more than 1 day on this error and not able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the `request` package to a new one. Looks like this was fixed in version 2.73: https://github.com/request/request/pull/2240

Comment: @lepsch, I will upgrade and provide the update

Comment: it is still failing

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade your `node` version to a new one? The version `5` have been outdated a long long time ago: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/#releases. You should be on the version >= 12.

It's highly probably some dependency doesn't work anymore with Node `5` and is throwing this error

Comment: Can you also test removing all `^` from the version numbers just to test if fixing the versions work? That way you'd know that it's some dependency that's causing this error.

Comment: Thank you so much @lepsch for your suggestion, I will try and update you